# How to prevent JQuery from queing (chaining)

Tags: jquery, conditional-statements, jquery-animate

Scenario: You can click a Button and some Content will move (.animate) left.
When you click the button fast for about 3 times then JQuery ques 3 .animate left's in the order.

I dont want that! I will prevent that queing so the button will only work when the animation is done.
Thank you for every clou!

*Pseudo Code:*

**IF** #Content is NOT animated (stands still)

**THEN** On Click Button

Animate Contet CSS "left" + 900px

**ELSE** You can't click the button now. But ff you click the butto,n then it wont que another animation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [the `:animated` selector](http://api.jquery.com/animated-selector/) to run code based on the animated state of an element.

```
if( $('#Content').is(':not(:animated)') ) {
    // run your animation
}
```

This also uses [the `:not()` selector](http://api.jquery.com/not-selector/), and [the `.is()` method](http://api.jquery.com/is/) to return a boolean.

Or you could add a class to the button when the animation starts, and use that class as a flag to determine if the animation should run.

The class could also style the button to give feedback that it shouldn't be clicked again.

```
$('#myButton').click(function() {
    $button = $(this);
    if( !$button.hasClass( 'disabled' ) ) {
        $button.addClass( 'disabled' );
        $('#Content').animate({left: '+=900'}, function() { $button.removeClass('disabled') });
    }
});
```

Comment: Thank ya all for your response. Your 2nd code works very fine for me. Thank you.

Comment: Had never seen .is before. Thank you for teaching me something new!

Answer (score 2):

You could always [unbind](http://api.jquery.com/unbind/) the `click` event when it is pressed. Then pass a callback to [animate](http://api.jquery.com/animate/) that will re-bind `click` once the animation is complete.